# Repeat mean values based in a custom ordination

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a min to max custom ordination `"Class_0_1","Class_1_3","Class_3_9", "Class_9_25","Class_25_50","Class_50"`

```
library(dplyr)

my.ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/test_ants.csv")

my.ds$ClassType <- cut(my.ds$AT,breaks=c(-Inf,1,2.9,8.9,24.9,49.9,Inf),
    right=FALSE,labels=c("Class_0_1","Class_1_3","Class_3_9",
    "Class_9_25","Class_25_50","Class_50"))

my.ds%>% group_by(nest,ClassType)%>% summarize(avg=mean(AT))
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   nest [7]
    nest ClassType       avg
   <int> <fct>         <dbl>
 1     2 Class_9_25   19.0  
 2     3 Class_0_1     0.776
 3     3 Class_9_25   12.4  
 4     3 Class_25_50  29.4  
 5     4 Class_1_3     2.42 
 6     4 Class_9_25   17.0  
 7     7 Class_9_25   18.2  
 8     7 Class_25_50  33.1  
 9    10 Class_3_9     5.22 
10    10 Class_9_25   13.6  
11    10 Class_25_50  38.9  
12    10 Class_50    110.   
13  1066 Class_0_1     0.111
14  1067 Class_0_1     0.436
```

I'd like to repeat the last mean value inside the intermediate absent `ClassType` by `nest`. The desirable output for `nest` 3 for example is:

```
    nest ClassType       avg
   <int> <fct>         <dbl>
...   
      3 Class_0_1     0.776
      3 Class_1_3     0.776
      3 Class_3_9     0.776
      3 Class_9_25   12.4  
      3 Class_25_50  29.4 
...
#
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try using `complete` and `fill`

```
my.ds %>% 
  group_by(nest,ClassType)%>%
  summarize(avg=mean(AT)) %>%
  complete(ClassType, fill = list(avg = NA)) %>%
  fill(avg, .direction = "downup")

    nest ClassType      avg
   <int> <fct>        <dbl>
 1     2 Class_0_1   19.0  
 2     2 Class_1_3   19.0  
 3     2 Class_3_9   19.0  
 4     2 Class_9_25  19.0  
 5     2 Class_25_50 19.0  
 6     2 Class_50    19.0  
 7     3 Class_0_1    0.776
 8     3 Class_1_3    0.776
 9     3 Class_3_9    0.776
10     3 Class_9_25  12.4 
# … with 32 more rows
```